# NASM coprocessor - rounding works badly

Tags: assembly, x86, nasm, fpu

I've written a program which calculates the volume of bullet. For a radius of 1.2, I should get 7 (7.23 rounded down). Instead, I get 9.

I've looked at program line by line and I can't see where I've made the mistake. My code is shown below:

```
section .text
global _start

_start:

FINIT

FLD dword [radius] ;; st0 - radius
FLDPI ;; st0 - pi, st1 - radius

xor eax,eax
mov eax,4
mov [operator],eax
FLD dword [operator] ;; st0 - operator, st1 - pi, st2 - radius

mov eax,3
mov [operator2],eax
FLD dword [operator2] ;; st0- operator2, st1- operator, st2- pi, st3- radius

FXCH st1 ;; st0- operator, st1- operator2, st2- pi, st3- radius
FDIV st0,st1 ;; st0- operator/operator2 = 4/3, st1- operator2,  st2- pi, st3- promien
FXCH st3 ;; radius, operator2, pi, operator/operator2
FMUL st0,st0 ;; st0- radius^2
FMUL st0,st0 ;; st0- radius^3
FMUL st0,st3 ;; st0- radius^3 * 4/3
FMUL st0,st2 ;; st0- radius^3 * 4/3 * pi

FISTP dword [result]

xor eax,eax
mov eax,[result]
add eax,48
mov [result],eax

mov eax,4
mov ebx,1
mov ecx,result
mov edx,4
int 80h

mov eax,1
int 80h

section .data
radius dd      1.2
operator dd     0
operator2 dd    0
result   dd      0
```

Comment: Don't edit the question and remove all the original buggy code because people won't know why and where your code fails. If you like you can add the fixed code below

Answer (score 1, accepted):

In addition to the issue that Michael mentioned, you appear to be using radius<sup>4</sup> rather than radius<sup>3</sup>

> FMUL st0,st0 ;; st0- radius^2
>   FMUL st0,st0 ;; st0- radius^3 //  **r<sup>2</sup> * r<sup>2</sup> = r<sup>4</sup>, not r<sup>3</sup>**

Comment: That's right too, thank you. I'll fix it. But after all, in my way (for radius to the power 4) I should get something like 9, instead of 3, which I've got now. What's wrong?

Comment: @Martin Can you add a code block at the bottom of your question with your code that has the above two issues fixed so we can see what your code looks like now? Please leave the existing code block, though, so that the answers already here won't confuse people reading the question in the future.

Comment: OK, no problem. Before the moment I've got an expected result :). It turned out, I have forgotten about one unconditional jump.

Answer (score 2):

Here you're trying to load a couple of integers as if they were 32-bit floating-point values:

```
mov eax,4
mov [operator],eax
FLD dword [operator] ;; st0 - operator, st1 - pi, st2 - promien

mov eax,3
mov [operator2],eax
FLD dword [operator2] ;; st0- operator2, st1- operator, st2- pi, st3- promien
```

To load a 32-bit integer and convert it to floating-point you should use `FILD dword [foo]`.

From Intel's Software Developer's Manual:

> **FILD—Load Integer**
> Converts the signed-integer source operand into double extended-precision floating-point format and pushes the
>   value onto the FPU register stack. The source operand can be a word, doubleword, or quadword integer. It is loaded
>   without rounding errors. The sign of the source operand is preserved.

Comment: Thank you man. That's right, I've made this mistake :). For a radius I have still FLD, but for operators I set FILD. Everything seems me to be OK, but now I've got 3 as a result.